# ionic build failed[Error: Could not find JAVA_HOME. Try setting the environment variable manually] & Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: ionic-framework

[Does any one here seen this problem before i have already get android sdk install but i don't know what to do next Thanks for your helping XD(i am running ubuntu 15.10)]

> jn_0810@jacky-ng-xps:~/TakeAway$ ionic build android Running command:
>   /home/jn_0810/TakeAway/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /home/jn_0810/TakeAway add to body class: platform-android Running
>   command: /home/jn_0810/TakeAway/platforms/android/cordova/build 
>   [Error: Could not find JAVA_HOME. Try setting the environment variable
>   manually] ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:
>   /home/jn_0810/TakeAway/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed
>   with exit code 2 You may not have the required environment or OS to
>   build this project Error:
>   /home/jn_0810/TakeAway/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed
>   with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srLBR.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and **copy** that text from the picture as plain text in a code block, into the question **itself**.

Comment: alright i have the text copied would you like to tank a look thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable in your .bashrc file like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="path/to/android-dir"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got the ANDROID_HOME problem finished But the""Command failed with exit code 2 ""is still here the error message is down below Thanks again for helping XP


 Error: /home/jn_0810/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/n0tccy407/ The error showing now